# What happens to a question on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I am wondering what happens to a question on hold.
Is it removed from the forum completely?
Is it no longer searchable?
Is it no longer visible but rather archived.
Is it visible still to the author but not the public?
How long does one have to edit the question so as to put it in a format which is acceptable to the community?
The question I am interested in discussing in an acceptable format [is found here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515762/)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it removed from the forum completely?

No. In your example you have given a link that still works, so it has not been deleted

> Is it no longer searchable?

No. One can still search for questions that are on hold. Just take a question that is on hold and search for it to confirm this.

> Is it no longer visible but rather archived.
>   Is it visible still to the author but not the public?

It is still visible to the public. Questions become "invisible" on the home page if it receives enough down votes, and it becomes invisible to all users with <10k rep if it becomes deleted.

> How long does one have to edit the question so as to put it in a format which is acceptable to the community?

Indefinitely as long as the question is not deleted. In your case the question has an up voted answer on it, so this is very unlikely.

---

"On hold" just means the question isn't up to the desired quality of the site and needs to be improved. Once you edit the question it gets added to the "reopen queue" where other users can decide to reopen it if it is of sufficient quality. The "on hold" just prevents the posting of new answers.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning (or at least linking to) the auto-deletion criteria for old questions which have low scores and no upvoted answers.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that only the first edit puts an on-hold question into the Reopen queue, so that edit needs to make a significant change to the question.